# How to reset only when the switch is moved?

Tags: java, android

I have a switch in my setting dialog. I want to call `reset()` only when the switch is moved. How can I do it?

```
if (showSwitch.isChecked()) {
    show = true;
    editor.putBoolean("show", true);
    reset();
} else {
    show = false;
    editor.putBoolean("show", false);
    reset();                
}
```

Comment: It "moves" every time you click it, right? So, why the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

If `show` is different from the switch value, do something. No if-else is required.

```
if (show != showSwitch.isChecked()) {
    show = showSwitch.isChecked();
    editor.putBoolean("show", show);
    reset();
}
```